# How to update map data in Array? Flutter firebase

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I use Flutter. I would like to update the value of CH to be false in Firebase only for the week of 26/4/2020. When is there a way?

Failed Ex.cord:

```
_firestore.collection('member').document(uidMember[index])
.updateData({'statistics': [{'${submit}': val,}]});
```

[image]

Comment: Read the document, modify the array in memory, then write it back to the document.

Comment: Can you please provide some code. Where you have tried to read the data and anything related to this question?

Comment: I don't know get the data about that part is.
Ex._firestore.collection('member').document(uidMember[index])
.updateData({'statistics': [{'${submit}': val,}]}); X Failed

Answer (score 3):

Given the Firestore snippet you shared you can do something like the following code to update data:

```
var ref = _firestore.collection('member').document(uidMember[index]);
ref.get() => then(function(snapshot) {
    List<dynamic> list = List.from(snapshot.data['statistics']);
    //if you need to update all positions of the array do a foreach instead of the next line
    list[0].CH = false;
    ref.updateData({
        'statistics': list
    }).catchError((e) {
        print(e);
    });
}.catchError((e) {
    print(e);
});
```

**NOTE**: I haven't tested this so you might have to adapt it, but should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

First create a `List` which has the updated items. Create a `Map` using the list and then update this map to the cloud firestore:

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> updatedList = [...];
Map<String, dynamic> updatedData = {
  'statistics': updatedList,
};
  
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
collection 
    .doc('doc_id')
    .update(updatedData);
```